# Why is site_url hiding my html file

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to hide my url for the css and only display the relative path. here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="<?php echo site_url('css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then when i view in browser my source code shows this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="
```

How do i fix this. The file im using is a php file.

Comment: Why are you "trying to hide your url" with a function that returns the current site URL. If you want relative, use *nix-like relative file paths with `..` or an absolute with `/`.

Comment: Yeah your right, might as well. Just trying to follow a tutorial and the instructor used it with no problem and ive even copy pasted his code and nothing.

Comment: Have you defined your site_url in the config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you load the url helper?

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

You can also Auto Load the helpers if you want to only load them once

> To autoload resources, open the application/config/autoload.php file and add the item you want loaded to the autoload array. You'll find instructions in that file corresponding to each type of item.

[CodeIgniter AutoLoad](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/autoloader.html)

Comment: Wow, thank you! didnt think that was the problem before. Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I could not find the function site_url in the default php library, is PEAR enabled on your server?

if you want the relative path you could use:

```
<?php echo  $SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'css/bootstrap.min.css'; ?>
```

or just

```
../css/bootstrap.min.css
```

or directly from the root

```
/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Comment: That's because he's using CodeIgniter.

Comment: Frankey, that very first response gives an absolute URL, not a relative one.

Comment: Indeed, it should be $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']